# How to obtain the integral representation of Modified Bessel function $I_0(2)$?

Tags: calculus

It is known that

$\displaystyle I_0(2)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k!)^2} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta$
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)
But how do people derive the equation?

Comment: Consider $e^{2 \cos \theta}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n \theta}{n!}2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange the order of integration:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^n \theta}{n!}2^nd\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n \theta d\theta.$$
For the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n \theta d\theta$, it is zero when $n$ is odd and 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n} \theta d\theta=
\pi\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}.$$
So $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2}.$$